# Return button pressed in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to use a `UIAlertController` for multiple purposes. It has two buttons, cancel and OK. I would like to add it to a method and return the button press, so I could just check for the user's response and act on it.

Now, I can't return a value inside `block`. So, how would I go about this?

Thanks.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Atenção!", "Atenção!") message:NSLocalizedString(@"Você não finalizou a sua série. Se sair desta tela, irá zerar o cronômetro.", "") preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *cancelar = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancelar", "Cancelar") style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {
                                   [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                   // I would like to return this button press to the method calling this one. 
                               }];
    [alertController addAction:cancelar];

    UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", "OK") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {
                                   [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                   // I would like to return this button press to the method calling this one.
                               }];
    [alertController addAction:ok];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**UPDATE: Real use**

When user presses `back button`, it will call a method to check a condition. If the condition is met, the alert is shown and user needs to decide to leave screen or not. That's why it would be great to return the answer to the `IBAction` `back Button`.

Note: The whole idea is to have other methods, besides the `back Button`, also show the alert and get an response from user.

Comment: why dont you use this AlertController in your back button? Is this alert code written in some other method and not in the back button?

Comment: that would work. But if I want to use the `alertController` on other buttons? I would have to either repeat code or save the `alert` in a `property`.  Right? It just doesn't seem to be the best solution.

Comment: You can use blocks as I have shown in my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make use of blocks.

Create a method like this

```
- (void)alertWithResponse:(void (^)(BOOL didCancel))response {

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Atenção!", "Atenção!") message:NSLocalizedString(@"Você não finalizou a sua série. Se sair desta tela, irá zerar o cronômetro.", "") preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *cancelar = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancelar", "Cancelar") style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

                                   [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                   response(YES);
                               }];
    [alertController addAction:cancelar];

    UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", "OK") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

                                   [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                   response(NO);
                               }];
    [alertController addAction:ok];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Now in your back button, call this method like this

```
- (IBAction)backButtonCliccked:(id)sender {

    //your button logic...
    //.
    //.
    //.
    [self alertWithResponse:^(BOOL didCancel) {
        if(didCancel) {
            //alert returned Cancel
        } else {
            //alert returned OK
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: I get quite significant delays from the block running inside the callbacks, compared to the old UIAlertView. It's really annoying. It seems to be "broken as intended" as it now waits for the animation to finish. Can't seem to find a good way to solve this.

Comment: Could explain in detail exactly what is the issue you are facing? It may be you are not doing UI updates in the main queue.